# How do I use a Wacom Intuos 3 with OS X Mojave (10.14.5)?

Tags: hardware, wacom

I have a (2009) Wacom Intuos 3 (Model: PTZ-930) graphic tablet which actually works well and for my convenience. More importantly I'm used to it. Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore with OS X Mojave and the actual supported driver.

Is there a procedure I could try to make it work again?

Answer (score 2):

The Accessibility options seem to be key, initially. From [Wacom Intuos 3 Tablet Issues with Mojave OS. Does the CTL4100 work?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2555672)

> Go to System Preferences / Security and Privacy / Privacy Tab / Accessibility / click the lock in the bottom left corner of your window to unlock (you'll need your password), then you can select the Wacom tablet in there. I just had the same problem and this worked great for me. Hope it works for you!

In addition, there seem to be some additional steps requried to obtain full functionality. This thread on Reddit, [Solution for Intuos 3 PTZ-630 in macOS 10.14 Mojave](https://www.reddit.com/r/wacom/comments/9m6i29/solution_for_intuos_3_ptz630_in_macos_1014_mojave/), seems to have a fuller solution:

> Need to make sure you go to
>
> System Preferences >> Security and Privacy >> Privacy >> Accessibility
>
> and make sure that Photoshop and WacomTabletSpringboard are both added
>   AND checked on the right panel.
>
> ...
>
> My process (for what it's worth).
>
> - already had driver 6.3.15-3. Clicks not registered. Tablet    diagnostics say everything is good.
> - uninstalled driver redownloaded 6.3.15-3 and reinstalled.
> - didn't work. Uninstalled 6.3.15-3
> - reinstalled older 6.3.14-2. Didn't work. Uninstalled.
> - installed latest driver, 6.3.31-4 (definitely NOT for Intuos 3).    Didn't work. Uninstalled.
> - reinstalled 6.3.15-3. Didn't work.
> - found out about having to enable apps (WacomTabletSpringboard and    Photoshop) in the accessibility options. EUREKA! clicks now
>     registering, but Photoshop still with no pressure.
> - checked other graphic apps. Pressure recognised. Hmmmm.
> - leave Photoshop pretty much alone for a day, pressure now working.

also, in the same thread:

> After several fresh installs and restarts, i realized that there was a
>   new button towards the bottom right in Security & Privacy > General
>
> it was saying something along the lines of some stuff did not load on
>   restart. Button was labelled Allow
>
> I tapped on it and a dialog box that had two items in itpopped up, one
>   wacom and another one that was probably wacom related, i hit allow and
>   my pen's tap to click started functioning again. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it only help partially. The tablet seems to be recognised by my macbook pro 2018 but the up-to-date wacom driver itself is not available and doesn't

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully the extra steps will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and pointing me through the reddit thread. I will try my luck. :)

Comment: If it ends up providing the actual solution, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer using the tick icon. Also, I think a reboot may be required to load the drivers, in order to get photoshop working. The clue might be here: `leave Photoshop pretty much alone for a day`. Maybe the machine was rebooted at some point over the day...

Answer (score 0):

Intuos3, with wacom driver 6.3.15-3, on Catalina 10.15.5,,, seems everything fully functional.

[image]