# Cannot Add New Apps to Mac Catalina Input Monitoring on Security & Privacy

Tags: macbook-pro, display, driver, wacom

I'm trying to get my Wacom Cintiq Pro 13 working over a USB-C cable connection.

The Wacom instructions tell me to drag and drop Wacom Tablet Driver and Wacom Touch Driver into my "Input Monitoring."

However, Input Monitoring will not accept drag and drop. The empty list of apps displays "Apps that have requested access to monitor input from your keyboard will appear here."

What should I do here?

Comment: Would you edit this to list the version / date of the software you are using and what version of Catalina? There are some recent updates that might be as simple as get version Y. I’ll take the second question out as we strongly prefer one question per question.

Comment: Here's a similar question about Input Monitoring permission for Wacom drivers. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387315/18101

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is no way to add new app if no other app asked for this permision - there is no list with +/- buttons. I've installed discord - and it appeared in the list - then I was able to add WacomTabletDriver and WacomTouchDriver from /Library/Application Support/Tablet/ to this Input Monitoring apps list...

However, you may just have to add other apps that requested control like photoshop.

- [How do I use a Wacom Intuos 3 with OS X Mojave (10.14.5)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362199/how-do-i-use-a-wacom-intuos-3-with-os-x-mojave-10-14-5)

This is correct and Wacom is wrong. Apps have to ask formally for this entitlement in code, so Wacom needs to ship a fix so their application or driver asks for permission.

They are also correct for some people, once permission has been granted to software that asked properly, you can drag and drop, but that is either a bug or not how newer Apple software works.

Until it’s clear, update your Apple software if you feel the drag and drop is a bug that Apple will fix. Contact Wacom for an update or support when their instructions fail you.

Comment: Great answer Pawel. We see this with quite a few apps at work, I don’t have a definitive answer if Apple tightened things up and Wacom hasn’t adjusted or if this is a bug, but dozens of people have this issue and we haven’t heard back from Wacom support yet whether they ship an update or change their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

First Unlock the lock. You can then press the + button, on the finder window which will open you locate the path/executable of the app you wish to add, and add it.

Picture below

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what we do after running all macOS updates and then making sure our Wacom driver is fresh from their website.

Comment: If you have no existing apps in "Input Monitoring", the Wacom install will not add its drivers. To solve this: install, run and enable Input Monitoring for the trial version of "ColorSnapper 2".

Comment: @frog22man FYI the latest ColorSnapper does not make the initial request for Input Monitoring. That app does request Screen Recording privs. Perhaps it always asked for both, or it recently switched away from needing Input Monitoring (I don't know). Just putting this out there for the next person who tries.    My workaround is electrical tape. :-)